# Set image at row and column in uigridview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gridview

i am using UIGridView as GridView will be shown in view,Having 2 column and so on ......i m just using and UIImageView so that my image is set on each row at rowindex and column at index

Here is my Code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
//    
//    img_ary=[[NSArray alloc]init];
//    img_ary= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"car-image.png",@"slider-image.png",@"car-image.png",@"slider-image.png",@"car-image.png",@"slider-image.png", nil];
//    [self collectioncreate];

    CarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [CarArray addObject:@"image.png"];
      [CarArray addObject:@"car-image.png"];
    [CarArray addObject:@"car-thumnail.png"];
    [CarArray addObject:@"image.png"];

}


- (CGFloat) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid widthForColumnAt:(int)columnIndex
{
    return 160;
}

- (CGFloat) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid heightForRowAt:(int)rowIndex
{
    return 200;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfColumnsOfGridView:(UIGridView *) grid
{
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger) numberOfCellsOfGridView:(UIGridView *) grid
{
    return [CarArray count];
}

- (UIGridViewCell *) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid cellForRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex
{
    Cell *cell = (Cell *)[grid dequeueReusableCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.thumbnail.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[CarArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex && columnIndex]];
```

But my image is not set properly.image.png is shown in row,column(0,0)(0,1)(1,0)..and car-image.png is occured on (1,1).

Please Help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `[CarArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex && columnIndex]` to `[CarArray objectAtIndex:(rowIndex*2+columnIndex)]` in your `cellForRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex` method.

&& is Logical AND Operator, 0&&0, 0&&1,1&&0, are 0. and 1&&1 is 1. that's why you have weird images display. What you need is `rowIndex*(columnsPerRow)+columnIndex` here.

Comment: @sir do u know how to put them all value as mark or unmark if i want to delete any row column?

Comment: sir and what is (rowIndex*2+columnIndex) can u explain?

Comment: rowIndex*(columnsPerRow)+columnIndex,2 is column number per row.

Comment: and if i want to select row/column with checkmark then ? any idea?sir

Comment: you need a 2 dimension array or 1 dimension array to remember the check status. then check it in your cellForRowAt method.

Comment: sir how to go on anotherView Controller with did select row at index path code is below

Comment: - (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex
{
 NSLog(@"%d, %d clicked", rowIndex, colIndex);
}

Comment: it depends on what are you using. if you r using the UINavigationController, you can push it. otherwise you can just present it

Comment: got it sir how can i increase my reputation in stackoverflow so that i can add image so it will be quite easy to understand.

Comment: your question/answer is upvoted :), i do it for you.also you can put your image in your dropbox.and put link in your question for us to refer it.

Comment: how can i ask question or being attach with u so if i have any question then i simply ask u?